# How to link user information of firebase_auth with files uploaded to other databases

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am trying to make something like an image/video sharing application with flutter and firebase.

User registration and authentication with firebase_auth
File upload with firebase_storage
Saving data in cloud_firestore, etc.← Now here

I'm looking at, but I'm working with them, for example,

Link the user information (user id) and the uploaded file,
I want to know who uploaded each file,
What should i do?

If I could do that,
I can search files by user id,
I give points to each user according to the number of file uploads
I think you can do something like this.

Do I need to use firestore or something for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that a good approach to do this is create a collection for `videos` and for `images` in Firestore Database, or even a generic collection called `media`, where each document has the info about the uploaded media, such as type (video/image), the file's url from Firebase Storage,  user's id and the upload's date. You can create a model like this, by example:

```
class UserMedia {
  String userId;
  String mediaUrl;
  String mediaType; // media type can be video, image, audio, etc.
  DateTime uploadedAt;
}
```

Then in your Firestore Database you can create a structure like this:

```
/media/{userId}/{userMedia} //here userMedia is a document created with the model described above.
```

And do the same for Firebase Storage. You can save files inside folders that the Storage creates based on the path if it doesn't exists.
By example you can upload a file passing some variables such as userId and the Storage will create the folders, by example:

```
/media/{userId}/image_{userId}_{imageId}.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I think it can be achieved by the method you showed us.
I'll do some research so that I can implement it concretely.